# How to make apt_package notify another resource only if the package was installed?

Tags: chef-infra, apt

I want to have a resource that executes a delayed reboot after an installation of an update. From obvious reasons, I also want to make sure that the next time chef runs it will not execute that command.

I thought about solving this by having an "execute" resource with `action :nothing` that is subscribed to the `apt_package` resource that will notify it once it's done installing and only if the installation was performed (chef runs periodically and the next time around the resource should not install anything in practice because the specified version was theoretically already installed the first time)

Is there a way to make `apt_package` notify only if the package has been installed in that run?

Comment: that's what notifications do..

Comment: I guess I should have tried before I asked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, this is indeed what notifications are for.